# Why does `Empty` not work in this VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is supposed to check if a cell is empty and, if it is empty, paste the contents of B26 into that cell. If the cell is not empty, it moves on to check the cell below it. I tried using `IsEmpty` but that didn't work, so I figured Excel was defaulting all empty cells to 0. So I tried using `Empty`(as shown in the code below) but that doesn't work either.

```
Sub Part1_Component_1_Foam_Color()
'
' Transfers Component 1 Data if Foam or color
'

'
Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
Range("B26").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Protected_JD_Form.xls").Activate
    If Range("B27:C27") = Empty Then
        Range("B27:C27").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("B28:C28") = Empty Then
        Range("B28:C28").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("B29:C29") = Empty Then
        Range("B29:C29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("B30:C30") = Empty Then
        Range("B30:C30").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit Sub
    End If
Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells in B and C merged?

Comment: Have you tried using `""` instead of empty? Double quotes is a different way of saying empty. I've heard it's slower/not always as accurate, but it might work in your situation

Comment: What about `nothing`

Comment: @Rory Yes, they are merged.

Comment: @User30923 Double quotes was the first thing I tried, it didn't work either.

Comment: @Rory Good catch. It turns out to be an important point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B27:C27")) = 0 Then
```

instead of

```
If Range("B27:C27") = Empty Then
```

---

By the way, there is no need to select range before pasting data.

This code

```
    Range("B27:C27").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

can be replaced with

```
    Range("B27:C27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I like this approach. I usually use the `IsEmpty()` approach -- but then I have never had the occasion to do it with a merged cell. I didn't know before today that `IsEmpty(MergedCell)` returns False even if the merged cell is in fact blank -- but this `CountA` approach handles that nicely (although the actual output of the isEmpty in the merged case seems to depend on how you address the range).

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is there a reason other than the merged cells that my code wouldn't work?

Answer (score 4):

The use of `Empty` or `IsEmpty()` in VBA is primarily to see if a variable has been initialized however it is commonly misused to check if a Range has a value.

If you want to see if a Range is 'empty' then use:

```
If Range("B27").Value = vbNullString Then
    '// Do Something
End If
```

If you want to check that a Range with more than one cell is empty then you can use a `COUNTA()` argument:

```
If [COUNTA(B27:C27)=0] Then
    '// Do Something
End If
```

*(or the same thing using the WorksheetFunction class...)*

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B27:C27")) = 0 Then
    '// Do Something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try IsEmpty

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A1").Value) = True Then

End if
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried

`var = nz(YourValue,"")`

and then checking with

```
If var = "" Then 'moar code
```

or just checking with

```
If nz(YourValue,"") = "" Then 'moar code
```